# How to split a string by quotation marks, site operator and non quotation mark?

Tags: java, string, parsing

I get request from user like this

```
site:www.example.com \"hello world\" \"hi abc\" where are you
```

I want to extract and save url from this string then remove it from above String, it should look like this `"hello world" "hi abc" where are you` Now split remaining string into two string arrays

```
String str1 = {hello world, hi abc};
String str2 = {where, are, you};
```

how can I do this in java? 
User query can be in any order. Various examples:

```
 "hi" excitement site:www.example.com \"hello world\" \"hi abc\" where are you "amazing"   
OR
    Hello World friends
OR
 Greeting is an "act of communication" human beings "intentionally"
```

Comment: You can achieve this with [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and some [String functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) like `substring` and `replaceAll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code can help you:

```
static class ExtractResponse {
    String newStr;
    String site;
}

public static ExtractResponse extractSite(String origin) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("site:\\S* ");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(origin);

    ExtractResponse response = new ExtractResponse();
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        response.site = matcher.group().substring(5); // 5 is length of "site:"
        matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, "");
    }
    matcher.appendTail(buffer);

    response.newStr = buffer.toString();
    return response;
}
```

It will return response contains new string without site:* and url of site.
For example I used your cases from answer and comments:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "site:www.example.com \"hello world\" \"hi abc\" where are you";
    String str2 = "\"hello world\" \"hi abc\" site:www.example.com where are you";

    ExtractResponse response1 = extractSite(str1);
    System.out.println(response1.newStr);
    System.out.println(response1.site);

    ExtractResponse response2 = extractSite(str2);
    System.out.println(response2.newStr);
    System.out.println(response2.site);
}
```

Output:

> "hello world" "hi abc" where are you
>
> www.example.com
>
> "hello world" "hi abc" where are you
>
> www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

This is a very specific issue, below logic might be helpful to you. I suggest you perfect this while testing this with your actual data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test1 = "site:www.example.com \"hello world\" \"hi abc\" where are you";
    String regex = "\\b(https?|ftp|file|site):[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
    String[] info = test1.split("\"");

    //read url
    String url;
    if (info.length > 0 && info[0].trim().matches(regex))
        url = info[0].trim();
    else
        throw new RuntimeException("Not a valid input");

    // read str1
    String[] info1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(info, 1, info.length - 1);
    String str1 = mkString(info1, ",");

    //read str2
    String[] info2 = info[info.length - 1].trim().split("\\s");
    String str2 = mkString(info2, ",");


    System.out.println("URL: " + url + " STR1: " + str1 + " STR2: " + str2);

}

// returns a delimited and curly parentheses {} enclosed string
public static String mkString(String[] input, String delimeter) {
    String result = "{";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
        if (input[i].trim().length() > 0) {
            result += (input[i] + delimeter);
        }
    }
    result += (input[input.length - 1] + "}");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: User can give query in any order: "hi"  excitement site:www.example.com \"hello world\" \"hi abc\" where are you "amazing"

Comment: Could you please update this in question? It not clear in there. Also, what you are asking is a very specific use case. I suggest you use regex, like the one i have above for url, for other strings as well. Ex for quoted strings, regex would be - (?:(?<=^")|(?<=\s")).*?(?="(?:\s|$))|(?![\s"])\S+